# Slumdog millionaire (2)

Tags: knowledge, science

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 200 Euro question:

> After my success in the first round, I started to feel a bit more confident.
>   Prem Kumar cleared his throat, rolled his eyes, stretched his neck like a
>   gander and started to read the 200 Euro question. I sat up straight and feverishly looked through the answers.  All four answers were single letters!
>
> I immediately discarded the second and the third answer; it was more likely
>   to find them around restrooms, and of course ladies were always first.
>   However, I wasn't quite sure about the first and the fourth answer:  most
>   ornithologists (and indeed also most people from the street) talk about the
>   shape being the first answer, but I had always seen it looking more like
>   the answer D, although they both were pretty similar letters.  However,
>   since this *is* a quiz show at popular culture and trivia level, I decided
>   to go with conventional wisdom and to choose the first answer.

What was the 200 Euro question?
What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?

Comment: BTW, the Indian prize money tiers are 5,000 and 10,000 rupees respectively. Here's the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaun_Banega_Crorepati) with the rest of them.

Comment: Is the quoted section an actual quote? I'd like to read the source if it is.

Comment: @JoeZ. just because Jamal is Indian doesn't mean he was on the Indian version of the game.

Comment: @kaine - I think he's referring to the fact that the title is [slumdog millionaire](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slumdog_Millionaire).

Comment: I don't get why you keep writing unconsistent plots talking about Euros and an Indian host on what you claim to be the Italian version of this quiz-show, but still.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is:

> Which letter is the shape of the formation migratory birds fly in?
>
> A) V
> B) W
> C) M
> D) Y

Reasoning:

> As Ben pointed out, W and M stand for "women's" and "men's" restrooms, respectively. W is choice B rather than C because "ladies were always first." The talk about ornithologists and ganders suggests that the actual question relates to birds, so we're looking for a letter that has some connection to birds. Migratory birds are usually said to fly in a V formation, so a question about migration patterns makes sense, and the "conventional wisdom" would be to answer V. In reality, the birds' shape isn't always a perfect V, so Jamal might be more familiar with other shapes.
>
> Sometimes it looks like a Y:
>
> [image: Y-shaped formation]
>
> Other times it looks (sort of) like an A:
>
> [image: A-shaped formation]
>
> It would be pretty confusing for choice D to be the letter A, since A is the label of a different choice, so I think it's more likely that choice D is the letter Y.

Comment: Yeah I like your answer better. Upvoted :)

Comment: And on the subject of having the option D:A, there's this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vzo9gLAGnA

Answer (score 8):

I'm not too confident on this one, but is the question:

> What shape are birds' feet?

With the choices being:

> A: Y
> B: W
> C: M
> D: X

Explanation:

> W and M, indicating Women's and Men's, are letters commonly found around restrooms. The hint about ornithologists implied that the question has something to do with birds and since W and M are similarly shaped, it would make sense that the question is asking a bird-related question about something shaped like those letters.
>
> The most common bird order is Passeriformes, which consists of birds that have feet shaped in the "typical" 3 toes forward, 1 toe backward configuration (called anisodactyl). This is most similar to the letter Y, which most ornithologists and the general public would probably pick.
>
> However, birds such as some raptors and parrots have zygodactyl feet, in which the toes are arranged 2 in front and 2 in back (shaped like the letter X) Since Jamal is from India, it is likely that he has seen many tropical birds with these sort of feet.
>
> A diagram illustrating this:
> [image: Diagram of different arrangements of bird toes]

Answer (score 0):

The question:

> What letter of the alphabet was the Pacman character based on?

Options:

> A: O
> B: F (possibly L - for ladies)
> C: M (possibly G - for gentlemen)
> D: C

Explanation:

> Restroom F = Female, M = Male. Order based on *ladies were always first..*.
>  O & C *...both were pretty similar letters*.
>  Also references *popular culture*

Comment: Interesting thoughts but this makes no account for the ornithologist comment in the question.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn yeh I know, i did actually consider the migratory birds option but ruled it out for some reason